# Sequential execution of generic SSIS package from multiple files

Tags: sql, batch-file, ssis

I have a generic SSIS package which is used for  multiple files upload and there is only one batch file for triggering this package which is expecting a call from scheduler for different files.

The problem is all the files will get into the system at the same time and ESP will trigger the same batch file multiple times for each file .

I have a Execute SQL task component as my first component in the package which will delete the data from the table since multiple times these package is getting called table is loosing data for single file .

I want to synchronize this behavior meaning I want to run the package again for the other file only once first file load is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a schedule table, then create foreach loop as the first component called. There would be an oledb source for your schedule table that the loop would iterate through to get the list of files. e.g. Once the first file is uploaded, execute sql task to update the schedule table with updatedatetime. The schedule table would contain a row for each file. You would select which files to upload by something like select * from schedule where updatedatetime < getdate() -.5 After the first one is done,  you execute another sql task to truncate the table and call the next one in the schedule table.